# Is this query actually working?

Tags: mysql, deadlock

This is from `show engine innodb status`

```
---TRANSACTION 4FF4, ACTIVE 43350 sec, OS thread id 6232 fetching rows
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
480318 lock struct(s), heap size 46578104, 48647170 row lock(s), undo log entries 377
MySQL thread id 21, query id 172 localhost 127.0.0.1 root Sending data
update sorted_tc

left join ana on ana.TCKIMLIKNO=sorted_tc.TCKIMLIKNO

SET sorted_tc.ADI = ana.ADI,

sorted_tc.SOYADI = ana.SOYADI,

sorted_tc.ANAADI = ana.ANAADI,

sorted_tc.BABAADI = ana.BABAADI,

sorted_tc.DOGUMYERI = ana.DOGUMYERI,

sorted_tc.DOGUMTARIHI = ana.DOGUMTARIHI,

sorted_tc.NUFUSILI = ana.NUFUSILI,

sorted_tc.NUFUSILCESI = ana.NUFUSILCESI,

sorted_tc.ADRESILI = ana.ADRESILADI,

sorted_tc.ADRESILCESI = ana.ADRESILCEADI
TABLE LOCK table `rehber`.`sorted_tc` trx id 4FF4 lock mode IX
RECORD LOCKS space id 41 page no 4 n bits 400 index `PRIMARY` of table `rehber`.`sorted_tc` trx id 4FF4 lock_mode X
TABLE LOCK table `rehber`.`ana` trx id 4FF4 lock mode IS
RECORD LOCKS space id 13 page no 4 n bits 176 index `GEN_CLUST_INDEX` of table `rehber`.`ana` trx id 4FF4 lock mode S
RECORD LOCKS space id 13 page no 5 n bits 176 index `GEN_CLUST_INDEX` of table `rehber`.`ana` trx id 4FF4 lock mode S
RECORD LOCKS space id 13 page no 6 n bits 176 index `GEN_CLUST_INDEX` of table `rehber`.`ana` trx id 4FF4 lock mode S
RECORD LOCKS space id 13 page no 7 n bits 176 index `GEN_CLUST_INDEX` of table `rehber`.`ana` trx id 4FF4 lock mode S
RECORD LOCKS space id 13 page no 8 n bits 176 index `GEN_CLUST_INDEX` of table `rehber`.`ana` trx id 4FF4 lock mode S
RECORD LOCKS space id 13 page no 9 n bits 176 index `GEN_CLUST_INDEX` of table `rehber`.`ana` trx id 4FF4 lock mode S
RECORD LOCKS space id 13 page no 10 n bits 176 index `GEN_CLUST_INDEX` of table `rehber`.`ana` trx id 4FF4 lock mode S
TOO MANY LOCKS PRINTED FOR THIS TRX: SUPPRESSING FURTHER PRINTS
```

Is it possible to figure out if this transaction is actually processing something or deadlocked?

I am using Maria DB 5.3 64 bit on windows 10.

I can provide additional info if required.

Comment: I have decided to kill this transaction. I am not deleting this question in case someone is in process of preparing an answer.

Comment: How big are the two tables?  They sound huge.  Or maybe some settings are especially small -- How much RAM do you have, what are the values of the `innodb_%` variables?

Comment: @RickJames There are 48 million rows. My innodb_buffer_pool size was 12G when I was executing this transaction.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` (modify the `UPDATE` to look like a `SELECT`).